# Laravel UserTableSeeder

Tags: php, laravel

I have started developing a new website with Laravel and AngularJS.

When I create my UserTable I want to populate it with some values using `php artisan db:seed`, but I get the following message:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     parse
>   error, expecting `')''

Here is my code for DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User Table seeded');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

and UserTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(array(

            'first_name'    => 'Thomas',
            'last_name'     => 'ERAUSQUIN',
            'email'         => 'te@et-project.net',
            'username'      => 'etadmin',
            'password'      => Hash::make('test'); //hashes our password nicely for us

        ));

    }

}
```

I have already tried running `composer dump-autoload`
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hash::make('test'); should be Hash::make('test'), - Comma, not semi-colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the semi-colon you have here:

```
Hash::make('test');
```

To:

```
Hash::make('test')
```

You are ending the statement early by leaving the semi-colon there and PHP doesn't know how to process it properly.

Answer (score 1):

ok thank that solve my problem, but now he give me this new error.

> ```
>     [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
>   Class 'Seeder' not found
> ```

I have try to add this before my class into UserTableSeeder.php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

but message error is

> ```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
>   Class 'User' not found
> ```

so don't really understand what happen

PS: I find the good way

here the good code for code work perfectly

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User as User;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
    DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(array(

            'first_name'    => 'Thomas',
            'last_name'     => 'ERAUSQUIN',
            'email'         => 'te@et-project.net',
            'username'      => 'etadmin',
            'password'      => Hash::make('test') //hashes our password nicely for us

        ));

    }

}
```

So before your class User for add one or some user you need add just after

this code

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User as User;
```

Second part for my answer find [here](https://sheepy85.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/laravel-5-authentication-users-migration-seed/)

Regard

Comment: Can you post this as a new question please - answers aren't the best place ;)